# Cancel the indentation of leaf nodes in an AdvancedDataGrid tree

Tags: apache-flex, flex-datagrid

I have an AdvancedDataGrid structured as a tree. Since the non-leaf nodes have an arrow to open/close them (I have no icons), their labels start just after the arrow, and the leaf nodes in the same level are indented to be aligned to them. I want to cancel that indentation so the leaf nodes will start from the beginning of the column. I tried to set the indentation to 0, but it doesn't have any effect.
Does anybody know how to do that, if at all possible?
Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So as I said in my comment, I used AdvancedDataGridGroupItemRenderer. I created a subclass of it and overrode updateDisplayList, in which I set the dimensions of the disclosureIcon field to 0. That did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

there is no need to use a custom renderer for that. Just set the `displayDisclosureIcon` property of `AdvancedDatagrid` to false.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can override the AdvancedDataGridItemRenderer or you can replace it with your own renderere. However, the ADG renderers take care of a lot of things automatically, so approach this with caution.

Comment: It's actually the AdvancedDataGridGroupItemRenderer.